# HTML5 Canvas: globalCompositeOperation (eraser)

Tags: javascript, canvas

*How can I use globalCompositeOperation for erasing something?*

http://canvaspaint.org/ has an eraser, but that's just a white line - ok only if your background is white...

I know you can use ctx.clearRect(). But it didn't really worked for me because while dragging a mouse with eraser (set to 8x8px) it only makes unconnected 8x8px squares - not really a smooth line.

Is there a way how to use globalCompositeOperation as an eraser?

Something like:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "___something___";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(mouseX , mouseY);
ctx.closePath();
```

Thank you.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328906/erasing-in-html5-canvas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can erase using globalCompositeOperation [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328906/erasing-in-html5-canvas/3334204#3334204).  Just set it to `"copy"` and use e.g. `strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"` and that will clear the canvas in the stroke.

**Update:** thanks for pointing out this doesn't work now @will-huang. You should as mentioned have globalCompositeOperation set to `destination-out` and strokeStyle set to `rgba(0,0,0,1)`.   (Actually you can have any RGB values, just you need the alpha set to 1.0 to fully erase the contents of the stroke.)

Here's an example of erasing: http://jsfiddle.net/FGcrq/1/

Comment: assign globalCompositeOperation to "copy" unable to run correctly in IE9/IE10.  I was changed to "destination-out" and change strokeStyle to "rgba(0,0,0,1)" to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
```

That should do the trick.  You can also use "xor" for erasing goodness.

Comment: I agree.     context.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.7)";       context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out" is better than "copy" because you can adjust eraser to different strengths.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  But just change the line color to whatever the background color is.  Also, if you want different sizes of eraser increase the line size.  `ctx.lineWidth=//default 1.0`
and `ctx.strokeStyle=//default black`  I would also suggest using `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` so you don't have to worry about resetting your line attributes.

Comment: http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/ has really nice eraser, but I can't figure out how it works.