# Erasing previously drawn lines on an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

To play around with HTML5 canvas, I decided to make an app which draws an analogue clockface. Everything's fine, except that old lines don't get erased in the way that I would expect. I've included part of the code below - DrawHands() gets called once a second:

```
var hoursPoint = new Object();
var minutesPoint = new Object();
var secondsPoint = new Object();

function drawHands()
{
    var now = new Date();

    drawLine(centerX, centerY, secondsPoint.X, secondsPoint.Y, "white", 1);
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    secondsPoint = getOtherEndOfLine(centerX, centerY, 2 * Math.PI / 60 * seconds, 0.75 * radius);
    drawLine(centerX, centerY, secondsPoint.X, secondsPoint.Y, "black", 1);

    drawLine(centerX, centerY, minutesPoint.X, minutesPoint.Y, "white", 3);
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    minutesPoint = getOtherEndOfLine(centerX, centerY, 2 * Math.PI / 60 * minutes, 0.75 * radius);
    drawLine(centerX, centerY, minutesPoint.X, minutesPoint.Y, "black", 3);

    drawLine(centerX, centerY, hoursPoint.X, hoursPoint.Y, "white", 3);
    var hours = now.getHours();
    if (hours >= 12) { hours -= 12; } // Hours are 0-11
    hoursPoint = getOtherEndOfLine(centerX, centerY, (2 * Math.PI / 12 * hours) + (2 * Math.PI / 12 / 60 * minutes), 0.6 * radius);
    drawLine(centerX, centerY, hoursPoint.X, hoursPoint.Y, "black", 3);
}
```

To make sense of the above, there are two helper functions:

- drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, thickness)
- getOtherEndOfLine(x, y, angle, length)

The problem is that while all the hands get drawn as expected in black, they never get erased. I would expect that since the same line is drawn in white (the background colour) it would effectively erase what was previously drawn at that point. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For reasons that I could expand upon, you should consider clearing your canvas and redrawing it entirely unless there are performance or compositing reasons not to.

You want [clearRect](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-clearrect), something like this:

```
//clear the canvas so we can draw a fresh clock
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

//redraw your clock here
/* ... */
```

Comment: If one were to want to clear a specific line or shape (as I did), rather than clearing a rectangular region, setting `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"` -- as mentioned in andrewmu's solution to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328906/erasing-in-html5-canvas) -- will pretty much make your fill/stroke operations act just like an eraser tool.  Remember to change the compositing mode back when you're done.  See the [Mozilla's compositing and clipping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing) for full details.

Comment: It is not necessary to always clear the canvas entirely.  See Simon Sarris's answer using getImageData / putImageData, which allows you to restore the drawing to any previous phase(s) of the drawing.

Comment: Correction on above comment - that should read mrmcgreg's answer.

Answer (score 27):

Instead of erasing the things you don't want you can:

1. save the state of the canvas
2. draw the things you don't want
3. restore the canvas to the saved state to 'erase' them

This can be accomplished pretty easily using `ImageData`:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fillRect(0,0,200,200);

// save the state of  the canvas here
var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// draw a red rectangle that we'll get rid of in a second
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(50,50,100,100);

setTimeout(function () {
    // return the canvas to the state right after we drew the blue rect
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200>
```

Comment: This method has an advantage over using clearRectangle, in that you can getImageData at any phase of the drawing and restore to that level, whereas clearRectangle will always take you back to a blank canvas.  For this reason I upvoted.

Comment: ...You could even take snapshots at several points in the drawing process if needed to restore to.

Comment: This can also keep you from having to reload an image if you are using one for a backdrop.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you can't just redraw the line in white and hope for it to erase the old line is because there might be some anti-aliasing/bleeding. You'll also notice that a straight horizontal line drawn on a pixel versus a half-pixel looks very different because of this.

When you do your white "erase" lines, try drawing them with a larger `lineWidth` by about 3 or 4. That should work for your case.

You should also draw all of the white lines first, then all of the black lines, in case they intersect.

Answer (score 4):

A quick and easy way to clear a canvas is to set the width:

```
context.canvas.width = context.canvas.width;
```

Comment: Smells like depending on some particular implementation in a particular browser, which is an easy way to undefined behaviour in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is double buffering :

```js
var shapes = 
  [{type:"circle", x:50, y:50, radious:40, lineWidth:2, strokeStyle:"#FF0000", fillStyle:"#800000"}
  ,{type:"rectangle", x:50, y:50, width:100, height: 100, lineWidth:2, strokeStyle:"#00FF00", fillStyle:"#008000"}
  ,{type:"line", x1:75, y1:100, x2:170, y2:75, lineWidth:3, strokeStyle:"#0000FF"}
  ];

step1();
setTimeout(function () {
  step2();
  setTimeout(function () {
    step3();
  }, 1000);
}, 1000);

function step1() {
  clearCanvas('myCanvas1');
  shapes.forEach((sh) => { drawShape('myCanvas1', sh); });
};

function step2() {
  clearCanvas('myCanvas2');
  shapes.pop();
  shapes.forEach((sh) => { drawShape('myCanvas2', sh); });
  showOtherCanvas('myCanvas2', 'myCanvas1');
};

function step3() {
  clearCanvas('myCanvas1');
  shapes.pop();
  shapes.forEach((sh) => { drawShape('myCanvas1', sh); });
  showOtherCanvas('myCanvas1', 'myCanvas2');
};

function showOtherCanvas(cnv1, cnv2) {
  var c1 = document.getElementById(cnv1);
  var c2 = document.getElementById(cnv2);
  
  c1.style['z-index'] = 3;
  c2.style['z-index'] = 1;
  c1.style['z-index'] = 2;
}

function clearCanvas(canvasID) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,480,320);
} 

function drawShape (canvasID, info) {
  switch (info.type) {
    case "line"      : drawLine(canvasID, info);
    case "rectangle" : drawRectangle(canvasID, info);
    case "circle"    : drawCircle(canvasID, info);
  }
}

function drawLine (canvasID, info) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = info.strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth = info.lineWidth

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(info.x1, info.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(info.x2, info.y2);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawRectangle (canvasID, info) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.fillStyle = info.fillStyle;
  ctx.strokeStyle = info.strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth = info.lineWidth

  ctx.fillRect(info.x, info.y, info.width, info.height);
  ctx.strokeRect(info.x, info.y, info.width, info.height);
}

function drawCircle (canvasID, info) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.fillStyle = info.fillStyle;
  ctx.strokeStyle = info.strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth = info.lineWidth

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(info.x, info.y, info.radious, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(info.x, info.y, info.radious, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="480" height="320"
 style="border: 1px solid #000000; position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; z-index:1">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="480" height="320"
 style="border: 1px solid #000000; position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; z-index:2">
</canvas>
```

The change is so fast you won't see any flicker.