# How to clear specific line in canvas using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm looking for a way to delete a specific line without clearing and redrawing it.
[How to clear specific line in Canvas : HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140805/how-to-clear-specific-line-in-canvas-html5)
I saw this question but everyone said you must clear all the page and redraw.
but is there a better way without drawing and clearing?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: thats so bad.now i should work more

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is how most rendering works.

Comment: If you are looking for a "shortcut" ... You could use a canvas library like http://fabricjs.com/ that does that for you

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a way! Try entering the coordinates of the sentences x and y and its width and height. This way you can clear only a portion of canvas. ctx.clearRect() actually clears a rectangle on the canvas and is used to clear the whole canvas by giving it 0 as the x, 0 as the y and giving it the width and height of canvas.